# Load Data in Array

Tags: arrays, swift

i want to load data in array when i go in the view controller.When i print the array, it is empty but if i use a refresh and print again the array, he is loaded.It is the code :

```
var information = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadinformation()
    print(information)
}

func loadinformation() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let prof = ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("interess")
    prof.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let name = dict["FullName"] as! String
            self.information.append(name)
        }
    })


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
prof.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
```

is asynchronous which means it's doesn't run as the serial flow of code , you need to print it here

```
let name = dict["FullName"] as! String
self.information.append(name)
print(self.information)
```

//

Or use completion

```
func loadinformation(completion:@escaping(_ arr:[String]?) -> Void ) {
    var arr = [String]()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let prof = ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("interess")
    prof.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let name = dict["FullName"] as! String
            arr.append(name)
            completion(arr)
        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })

}
```

Call

```
loadinformation { (result) in
  print(result)
  if let content = result {
    self.information = content 
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: i have a collection view where in every cell i have a label where the text is the value of array[indexpath.row]

Comment: i hide the other code because my problem is the array

Comment: reload the collection inside the callback

Comment: unnder self.information.append... i write collectionview.reloadData()

Comment: try the edit it should refresh the collection , your old reload ran before the result returns

Comment: BTW I don't see any for loops for the array

Comment: What **print(result)** gives you ??

Comment: it print the correct result but initally the array is always empty

Comment: this where you should go , don't care about other parts , they're miss-leading , suppose that the request to firebase  takes 2 mintues , if you think that the app is pausing the print line until that , then you miss-understand asynchronization